# Not getting image src value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following html

```
<div class="row1">
  <div id="chart_1" class="chart">
     <img src="//chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&amp;chs=900x300&amp;chdlp=r&amp;chdl=Date%7CSMR%2020%2FSICOM20&amp;chco=3399CC%2C80C65A&amp;chxt=y&amp;chxr=0%2C1%2C37.8&amp;chd=e%3AAABvDeKbMKWm%2C..z.qbLeTpFk" class="charts-serverchart-image" width="900" height="300">
  </div>
</div>
```

I use following jquery code to get src value form image but not getting. Please help me

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   data = $('#chart_1 img').attr('src');
   alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5zmqr4vu/1/ Which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine, see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zmqr4vu/)

You can try this, if you want:

```
data = $('#chart_1').find("img").attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `prop`

```
$('#chart_1 img').prop('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ".prop" method to get better results. It will will you complete src (http or https included) Demo http://jsfiddle.net/5zmqr4vu/2/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    data = $('#chart_1 img').prop('src');
    alert(data);
});
```